# You are getting this "catch-all" property because of the following reason

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I have a scenario like below in the last of exception, when I am trying to get the JAXB Class through xjc tool getting the bellow error:

*** You are getting this "catch-all" property because of the following reason:**
     *** The field name "AbcDef" is used by two different parts of a schema. See:**

```
 ** line 4 of file:/D:/svn/src/main/resources/schema/Domain.xsd*

 ** line 5 of file:/D:/svn/src/main/resources/schema/Domain.xsd*
```

I tried to change the name of both property in bindings.xml file but doesn't workout, please let me know. how i can handle this scenario.

```
<xs:element name="Sample">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="AbcDef" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element ref="abc_def" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
```

Comment: What does your `bindings.xml` file look like? Maybe you made a mistake there, and if you show it someone can help you fix it.

Comment: <bindings schemaLocation="./Domain.xsd">

<bindings node="//xs:element[@name='abc_def']">
            <class name="abc_def_LC" />
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='AbcDef']">
            <class name="AbcDef_CC" />
        </bindings>

Comment: @Jesper Can you please see above comment ?

Comment: How are you calling xjc? Are you passing the bindings file using `-b bindings.xml`? Try using `schemaLocation="Domain.xsd"` without `./` in front of the schema name. This should work normally, but if the bindings file seems to have no effect, then you're probably not passing it correctly to xjc.

Comment: @Jesper I am calling like this xjc -d ..\..\java -p com.grp.domain.generated Domain.xsd -b bindings.xml -extension and bindings.xml file is also reflecting.. seems different issue